# Capybara warning: ignoring the provided expectation [...] since it is not a string or a proc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I use RSpec and Capybar to test my applicaiton. In one of my feature spec I want to assert that a field has a certain value. When I use Capybara's `find_field` I get some strange behavior. (The below code runs with capybara-webkit since the field value is rendered by AngularJS, if that is of importance).

This code works fine:

```
expect(find('input[name=ordered_quantity]').value).to eq '0'
```

But I would rather use the `find_field ..., with: ...` method, which I think is a bit cleaner than `find(...).value`. The following code passes, but with a warning, which indicates that it is ignoring the `with` filter:

```
is_expected.to have_field('ordered_quantity'), with: '0'
# => WARNING: ignoring the provided expectation message argument ({:with=>"0"}) since it is not a string or a proc.
```

The following code (`input[name=ordered_quantity]` added) both fails and gives me a warning:

```
is_expected.to have_field('input[name=ordered_quantity]'), with: '0'
# => WARNING: ignoring the provided exptheectation message argument ({:with=>"0"}) since it is not a string or a proc.
```

There is only one occurrence of `ordered_quantity` on the page and that is the field I want to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put the `with: '0'` inside of the `have_field` method:

```
is_expected.to have_field('ordered_quantity', with: '0')
```

Comment: Great! That worked!

Then what does Capybara try to do when I put `with: '0'` outside the call to `have_field`?

Comment: I think rspec handles that call, since the calling method is `is_expected.to`. After the `to` method, rspec expects a "matcher", such as `have_field`, `eq`,  `change`, etc. Since `with: '0'` is an invalid matcher, you get this warning.